# How to download openSUSE 12.1 throught `wget -c`?

Tags: opensuse, wget, firefox

http://software.opensuse.org/121/en

Usually I right click and open the download link in a new tab. Copy the url on the command line with `wget -c`.

In this case I just can't right click on the download button!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Click on it, it will start downloading in browser. Cancel downloading immediately. Copy the link from "Download" tab and use it for wget.

Comment: @SHW Where do I click on the download tab? See the screenshot in OP.

Comment: In the download tab, click cancel. Right click on seek bar, copy download link.

Comment: @SHW I hovered on the link in the dialog box and it showed the url, I copied that url and pasted next to wget. I think it is done now. Thanks to you. **I request you to post this as an answer so that I can select it.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on it, it will start downloading in browser. Cancel downloading immediately. Copy the link from "Download" tab and use it for wget